# Displaying staffname,subject name and max marks scored in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-order-by, where-clause

This is the question statement the code should be in oracle..
Write a query to display list of staff name, subject name handled, maximum mark scored in that subject. Give an alias to the maximum mark as max_mark. Sort the result based on maximum mark in descending.
[This is the schema for the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x9UV.jpg)

I tried to use join to tackle this problem using this code.... but the results i get are weird.. please help as to get the proper result.

```
select staff_name,subject_name,value as max_mark
from subject
join staff using(staff_id)
join mark using(subject_id)
where(staff_id,value)
in(select staff_id,max(value)
from subject group by staff_id)
order by max_mark desc;
```

output i get is

[output-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpmSb.png)
[output-part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IULJ.png)

expected output is
[expected output-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l5IP.png)

Comment: what's weird for the results? Btw, there seems a closing parentheses is missing within the query.

Comment: yes i forgot to add the braces here .. will add it ,expected result is a single table .. and the values seems repeated at some places .. let me edit the post again to add the expected output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need maximum marks that is obtained by the student in the subject that is handled by the staff. Use `max` aggregate function as following:

```
Select st.staff_name, s.subject_name, max(m.value) as max_marks
  From staff st 
  join subject s
    On st.staff_id = s.staff_id
  Join marks m 
    on m.subject_id = s.subject_id
 Group by st.staff_name, s.subject_name, st.staff_id
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to use `MAX(..) OVER (PARTITION BY...)` analytic function :

```
SELECT staff_name,subject_name,
       MAX(m.value) OVER (PARTITION BY sb.staff_id) AS max_mark
  FROM subject sb
  JOIN staff st ON st.staff_id = sb.staff_id
  JOIN mark m   ON m.subject_id = sb.subject_id
 ORDER BY max_mark DESC
```

In this case `GROUP BY` is not needed `PARTITION BY` clause might be used instead.

Comment: this throws a column ambiguously defined error at staff_id at line 2 ..... :(

Comment: this throwed invalid identifier for the sb.value in 2nd line... got it Thanks for the helpp :D

Comment: excuse me I misprinted MAX(sb.value) which should be MAX(m.value) @bunbutter , can you try again?